# **glibc detected malloc() memory corruption: 0x0000000001f7df7***

Tags: c++, memory-management

I get an memory corruption error when I try to run the c++ code.

The code converts a list of names in a vector to json format.

```
void fetchName(vector<double>& Name,string& Nameoutput)
{
     Names_t *nameip=new Names_t();
       for (int k = 0; k < Name.size(); k++ )
       {
                std::ostringstream strs;
               strs << Name[k]; //The error occuse here if I comment this line
                                   and run it does not five an error
                nameip->jsonText->append(strs.str());
                nameip->jsonText->append(",");

            }
       Nameoutput= nameip->jsonText->data();

}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: does it crash at the first iteration or later?

Comment: as you have it now `nameip` causing a memory leak, but not necessarily related to the crash, maybe you could declare it as a normal stack variable `Names_t nameip;`

Comment: at the first iteration itself

Comment: judging from the code it looks ok (part from the memory leak), maybe the problem is that heap got corrupted elsewhere.